# return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

i have issue with my discord bot and i dont know how to fix it

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1338
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^
Error: /home/container/node_modules/skia-canvas/lib/v6/index.node: invalid ELF header
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1338:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/node_modules/skia-canvas/lib/index.js:23:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
Node.js v18.15.0
```

i try reinstall pterodactyl and all node modules

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`/home/container/`
The path suggests you're using a container, and I'm assuming it is Docker - Did you make sure to ignore the node_module files in your Dockerfile? Chances are that it breaks when trying to use the existing `node_modules`

**In the container**, delete `node_modules` and reinstall the libraries using `npm install`
That should fix it, but a more permanent version would be to edit the `dockerignore` file to ignore `node_modules`